# Webpack 2.x Adding code to the compiled js

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

In the webpack configuration, I want to add js code that will ultimately be put in the public bundle. Basically I want to use webpack to transpile all of my javascirpt and then add on some console logs so that when I open up the page in the browser I see some webpack console.log messages.

Comment: Are you saying that you want console logs in the _browser_ for errors generated _during webpack's build_?

Comment: ultimately I want to be able to show the warnings thrown by tslint in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You should have an entry point specified in your webpack config file. Within that file, you can use require to tell webpack to append javascript files to the bundle. So just do require('logFile') and it will be added to the bundle. You will need something to call those functions, so since I'm not sure whether you are using a framework or just plain JS, I can't tell you how to execute your code.